# Deriving a Time-Dependent Equation from a Surge Arrester for Transient Voltage Analysis

Tags: electrical-engineering, mathematics

After looking through dozens upon dozens of IEEE papers, it seems that no one has really developed a simplified formula for a surge arrester.

What I would like to be able to do is perform a transient voltage study, and would like to be able to determine how the transient voltage would be impacted with the addition of a surge arrester, purely mathematically.

Is there a method of developing a "cutoff" equation for a surge arrester given its V-I data from a manufacturer?

For example:
$$\begin{array}{c} 
 & \text{Vrated (kV)}\\ \hline
\ 15kV\\ \hline
\end{array}
\begin{array}{c} 
 & \text{I(kA) (8/20µs), (kV)} \\ \hline
\ 1 (33.1) & 2.5(37.8) & 5(41.3) & 10(45.6) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

In the table above, 15kV is the rating of the surge arrester, and to the right is the characteristic curve (V-I) of the arrester, where the number on the outside is the current in kA and the number in parenthesis is the residual voltage in kV.

Does anybody know how to take a curve, such as the one above, and transform it into a time-dependent equation that I would 'subtract' from a sinusoidal transient voltage,

$$V(t) = [transient-waveform]-[surge -arrester-curve]$$

The only formula I've come across that characterizes manufacturer data and is used in EMTP software is:
$$I=p(V/Vref)^q$$

But it is not time dependent and absolutely no mentions how the 'p', 'q' and 'Vref' variables are calculated.

Comment: Better on the electrical stack...